# how return one of the function between OR operator?

Tags: javascript, recursion, return

I can not understand when the 'find' function will true or false in the **else** block. Here is the code:

```
function findSolution(target) {
  function find(current, history) {
    if(current == target) {
      return history;
    } else if (current > target) {
      return null;
    } else {
      return find(current + 5, `(${history} + 5 )`) || find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`);
    }
  }

  return find(1, "1");
}

console.log(findSolution(24));
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. It’s not clear to me what you want to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) works by first evaluating `` find(current + 5, `(${history} + 5 )`) `` and if it is [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) that is the final result. If it is [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) it will evaluate `` find(current * 3, `(${history} * 3)`) `` and whatever is the result will be the end result which is then returned.

You can replace `return expra || exprb` with code without `||` using `if` and bindings:

```
// expra and exprb can be any valid expression
// same as return expra || exprb;
const tmp = expra;  
if (tmp) {
    return tmp;
}
return exprb;
```